# ¿Cómo invierto los dígitos de cualquier número?

Tags: c++, algoritmos

He conseguido programarlo de tal forma que invierta los dígitos de un número no mayor que 9999. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con cualquier número entero sin tener que tener en cuenta esa restricción?. Sospecho que tengo que trabajar con strings.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int reverse(int numb);

int main()
{

int x;
    cout << "Number: " << endl;
    cin >> x;

    cout << reverse(x) << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int reverse(int numb)
{
    int m, c, d, u, newnumber;
    m = numb / 1000;
    c = (numb - (m * 1000)) / 100;
    d = (numb - ((m * 1000) + (c * 100))) / 10;
    u = (numb - ((m * 1000)+(c* 100)+( d * 10)));

    newnumber = (u * 1000 + d * 100 + c * 10 + m);
    return newnumber;
}
```

Comment: Bonito código. No `using namespace std;`, no `system("pause")`. Lo único que cambiaría sería `std::endl` por `'\n'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Muy sencillo, sustituye las llamadas fijas que estás haciendo por un bucle:

- Multiplicas el numero final por 10
- Sacas el digito menos significativo del numero a invertir
- Añades ese digito al numero final

Y repites hasta que no queden digitos en el numero original:

```
int reverse(int numb)
{
  int newnumber = 0;
  while( numb != 0)
  {
    newnumber *= 10;
    newnumber += numb % 10;
    numb /= 10;
  }
  return newnumber;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha parecido una maravilla lo que se puede hacer unicamente con mecanismos aritmeticos. No tenia ni idea.

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Como puedo hacerlo con cualquier numero entero? Sin tener que tener en cuenta esa restricción.

Es difícil no anclarse a una restricción ya que los tipos de C++ tienen un límite, por ejemplo, si inviertes el número 2.147.483.647 provocarás un [desbordamiento de `int`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_aritm%C3%A9tico), ya que precisamente ese valor es el máximo que puede contener un entero con signo. Podría solucionarse usando un `long long` cuyo valor máximo con signo es 9.223.372.036.854.775.807 (y que al invertirse, casualmente no supera su valor).

Si tu plataforma no da soporte a `long long` entonces tu intuición es correcta:

> Sospecho que tengo que trabajar con strings.

Con una cadena de caracteres no tendrás la limitación indicada, así pues este código:

```
std::string reverse(int numb)
{
    std::string result{};
    result.reserve(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits);

    while (numb)
    {
        std::cout << (numb % 10) << '\n';
        result.push_back('0' + (numb % 10));
        numb /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << reverse(2147483647);
    return 0;
}
```

Mostrará 7463847412 mientras que en la versión numérica habría provocado desbordamiento.

Comment: En mi humilde opinión su respuesta debería ser la aceptada por el OP.

Comment: La gracia es que haya variedad de respuestas válidas, variadas e interesantes, el que se acepte o no la respuesta es lo de menos ;P